# Scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

tengo este metodo en cada elemento que voy seleccionando, pero no me hace el scroll hasta arriba, que puede ser?

```
function() {
    console.warn("<br>Elemento del tipo: <b>" + document.activeElement.type + "</b>");
    var elemento = document.activeElement;
    var posleft = elemento.offsetLeft;
    var postop = elemento.offsetTop;
    console.warn("Left: " + posleft + "px - Top: " + postop + "px");
    //$('html, body').scrollTop(postop-300);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0 - 300}, 250);
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un ejemplo de codigo ejecutable para probar lo que dices?

Comment: Supongo que el error no es que uses en el animate constantes numéricas, en tu código real usas las variables que obtienes no? no el 300 y el 250...

Comment: Por qué `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0 - 300}, 250);` ? Es decir, 0-300 es simplemente -300, que para el caso es lo mismo que poner 0

Comment: Puede que no entienda bien tu pregunta. Tienes ese método al que llamas al poner el foco en un elemento, y lo que quieres es el navegador lo sitúe en el top de la vista no?, sino, puedes especificar un poco mejor lo qué quieres conseguir en la pregunta?